# Fail to use MS-RPC in Excel host

Tags: windows, ipc, rpc

I use RpcBindingFromStringBinding to connect from `MS-RPC` client to local Daemon server and vice versa. I use `LRPC` or local Named Pipes. Randomly calls to `NdrClientCall2` fails from first attempt, event if server is alive, `error code` is `-2147467259`. Freeing binding and creating new one and do request does not helps. It is reproduced when Excel process add-in start `Daemon` process, both can be server and client. Cannot reproduce on 2 console executable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RPC from C#. During start I got GC of RPC server handles. Not reproduced in tests until GC calls.